# Converting from Pixel Coordinates to UI Coordinates in Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know how to convert from Pixel Coordinates to UI Coordinates and vice-versa in Unity? Let's say for example I want to click somewhere on the screen with the mouse, and a UI Image to be at that click position. If I do this won't work:

```
Image img = null // I assign it via the inspector
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        img.rectTransform.anchorPosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Image img = null // I assign it via the inspector
void Update()
{

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector2 point;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle((RectTransform)img.rectTransform.parent, Input.mousePosition, canvasCamera, out point);
        img.rectTransform.anchorPosition = point;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. It worked. Thank you. For those who have this problem additional information: The canvas of the ui elements must be in Screen Space Camera mode. Also as the 3rd parameter of the ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle function use the camera that is used by the canvas.

Comment: This only works if the anchor point of the RT is centered. This requires an adjustment to appropriately place an image, as originally asked.